# Append data to wordpress get_header()

Tags: php, wordpress, append

In my Wordpress theme, I've got few custom post types with custom templates. These templates use additional data like specific CSS or Java Script.

Is there a way to append this kind of data to get_header() function, so i can alter it without hard-copying it inside my custom post type template?

In short, for example. Insert
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/interview.css" type="text/css" media="all">`
inside

```
get_header();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly then you need something like this:-

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
   global $post;
   $post_type = get_post_type( $post );
   if( $post_type === 'your-custom-post-type-slug-here' ) { // edit this line as per requirements
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style-interview', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/interview.css' );     
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

(*Thanks @TopDown for the performance tip in comments.*)

You just have to place the above code in your theme's Functions.php. For more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: You can also check the post type in the mentioned function above to save on http performance if this only needs to load on your post type. global $post; $post_type = get_post_type( $post ); Then check the $post_type var against your post type slug.